# Angular Material Datepicker for HH:mm

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I want to use `Datepicker` in my Angular, and I have checked this link [Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api), but I only want to show HH:mm.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Edit:
Currnetly, I tried Jquery control with below code, but I failed to set the selected Datetime to my model, it seems to be related with Angular Scope.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('#timepicker1').timepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            var newclass = 'admin-form';
            var themeClass = $(this).parents('.admin-form').attr('class');
            var smartpikr = inst.dpDiv.parent();
            if (!smartpikr.hasClass(themeClass)) {
                inst.dpDiv.wrap('<div class="' + themeClass + '"></div>');
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            ***//this.model is alwasy undefined***
            console.log(dateText)
        }
    });
    $('#timepicker2').timepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            var newclass = 'admin-form';
            var themeClass = $(this).parents('.admin-form').attr('class');
            var smartpikr = inst.dpDiv.parent();
            if (!smartpikr.hasClass(themeClass)) {
                inst.dpDiv.wrap('<div class="' + themeClass + '"></div>');
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            console.log(dateText)
        }
    });
    $('#timepicker1').timepicker('setTime', '08:00')
    $('#timepicker2').timepicker('setTime', '17:00')
}
```

UI:

```
                                <label for="address" class="col-md-2 control-label">营业时间：</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="timepicker1" class="field prepend-icon">
                                            <input type="text" id="timepicker1" name="timepicker1" class="gui-input" placeholder="开始时间">
                                            <label class="field-icon">
                                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                            </label>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label for="timepicker2" class="field prepend-icon">
                                            <input type="text" id="timepicker2" name="timepicker2" class="gui-input" placeholder="结束时间">
                                            <label class="field-icon">
                                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                            </label>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: The component explicitly says that it only supports basics features for now. Instead, you could try to use [primeNG components](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Comment: thanks, do you konw how could I change the css reference? Currently, it use in the node_modules, which is required refernce? Then I could add it in my component?

Comment: What ? What do you want exactly here ? I didn't understand a single thing.

Comment: I want a DatePicker with Time only. Your shared link helps a lot. But I failed to make it work in my own project. It seems to be related with css files.

Comment: Oh yes, you have to import the files in your angular-cli.json file. They explain all of it in the installation guide.

Comment: Yeah, I have imported the reference, in the guide project, it reference the css file in index.html. But my way is a little different, I used webpack to package, I need to reference the css in my component instead of index.html. It will not be found when I using in index.html